# Sextic twist maps to q Eigenspace of Frobenius

Tags: pairings

Let $E(p)$ be a Barretto-Naehrig elliptic curve with r-torsion and embedding degree 12 and $E'$ a sextic twist with homomorphism $\psi$.
How to show, that

- $E'$ has a unique r-torsion group
- $\psi$ maps the r-torsion of $E'$ to the Trace-0 subgroup of $E(p^{12})$

Comment: @cryptostase Why should we delete the question? I'm no expert in that area, but it looks like a valid question to me.

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, you could post an answer referencing the paper and preferably giving a short summary of the proof idea.

Comment: The proof can be found in the paper:
The Eta Pairing Revisited, section 5
F. Hess, N. Smart, and Frederik Vercauteren